# I cant import module from internal module files

Tags: python, module, discord.py

I want import a module in ***Modules*** Directory from inside the module itself, i create all **init** files with their config:

[image]

I am able to import all these modules into an **external** script, But when I want to import them from **inside** the module itself, like the image below:

[image]

I get this error:

```
    from modules.config.database import *
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'
```

Comment: If you're directly executing `main.py` from within the `modules\game` directory then it doesn't know about directory structures elsewhere, it just knows that there's no package named `modules` inside `modules\game`. Typically the script you execute would be at the top level.

Comment: If `main.py` is already in the modules folder, you don't have to add that. Could you try it with just `from config.database import *`?

Comment: yes but not working

Comment: if each directory only has a `__init__.py` and a `main.py` why not just remove that directory and just do like `game.py` or `member.py`